# How do you place more prophets on enemy islands in idle worship?

Tags: idle-worship

How does one place more prophets on enemy islands in [Idle Worship](https://apps.facebook.com/idleworship/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've discovered there's two ways to do it.

1) You can use blessings on an enemy mudling until their faith gets full blue, then make them a prophet.

2) You get bonus powers for free (except for the single power energy costs) guaranteed to make a mudling a prophet

*note*

You will need to keep **blessing** them to ensure that they stay prophetized to your side.